# Is it possible to use PHP validation before a form has been submitted and the page refreshed?

Tags: php, validation

I have created a user registration form using PHP, a password must be entered and entered again to check they both match. I have my conditional checks which are run when the form is submitted, if they fail, the form is reloaded empty for the user to fill in. I wanted to do a real time check against the password, and repeatPassword fields, so if they were both entered and did not match a warning displayed instantly, not after the whole form was filled in and submitted.

I have tried doing this using only PHP, I was using JavaScript before but I want to do it all in PHP as I think it will be better and more reliable.

Here is the code I have for my form checking condition:

```
$firstname=$_POST['fName'];
$surname=$_POST['sName'];
$email=$_POST['emailad'];
$password= md5($_POST['password']);
$repeatpassword= md5($_POST['repeatPassword']);
$secretquestion=$_POST['sQuestion'];
$secretanswer=$_POST['sAnswer'];
$address1=$_POST['address1'];
$address2=$_POST['address2'];
$address3=$_POST['address3'];
$address4=$_POST['address4'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$postcode=$_POST['postcode'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];

if(!empty($password)
&& !empty($repeatpassword)
&& !empty($firstname)
&& !empty($surname)
&& !empty($email)
&& ($repeatpassword == $password)
&& !empty($secretquestion)
&& !empty($secretanswer)
&& !empty($address1)
&& !empty($city)
&& !empty($postcode)
&& !empty($phone))
 {


$reg =true;
$sql = "INSERT INTO cryptuser (firstname,surname,email,password, secretq, secreta,
                               address1,address2,address3,address4,city,postcode,phone,mobile)
        VALUES     ('$firstname','$surname','$email','$password','$secretquestion','$secretquestion',
            '$address1','$address2','$address3','$address4','$city','$postcode','$phone','$mobile')";
```

I had code written which I deleted because it was definitely wrong, but I was trying to perform a PHP function, if the password and repeatPassword fields are not empty, check both values are the same, if they are do nothing, else display warning text.

I felt this would work, but I am still trying to get used to php being a server side language.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Bad code. Vulnerable to SQL injection and way too many conditionals. Also, instead of doing `$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];` you could do `extract($_POST)` which will import variables from the `$_POST` array into the current symbol table.

Comment: My code is bad, I know it is, I am building my way up teaching myself PHP and SQL, the help I receive here makes me a better programmer. Thanks for the tip, also could you provide a small example of your suggestion please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, it won't be "better and more reliable" in PHP than in Javascript. Both languages are Turing-complete and there's little you can do in one realm you can't do in the other. You're only limited by your ability as a coder.

That said, if you want to do the validation in PHP before the form is submitted, you're going to have to get the data to the server somehow. Of course, that process is much like submitting a form...

One means would be to have JS which scrapes the information from the form and makes an AJAX request to the server. If the server says "OK", then the JS sets the client location to the new page (since the server already received all the contents as part of the validation process, you shouldn't need to POST them again).

Moving on, your validation code as you've written it above is a **very bad idea**. See [this comic](http://xkcd.com/327/) for a fast-and-decent explanation why ( http://bobby-tables.com appears to be down) - imagine what the SQL query would look like if you had that as `$_POST['fName']`.

Comment: Sanitize your inputs with mysql_real_escape_string(). For example, $firstname=$_POST['fName']; will become $firstname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fName']);

Comment: @TomWill Please don't recommend that as opposed to parametrized queries. Why shouldn't people use PDO?

Comment: I am using SQL Server unfortunately, is there an alternative to this version mysql_real_escape_string? I was thinking of using params once I get all my forms working and validating, then getting everything secure, as a beginner, the less PHP and SQL code there is in my scripts the easier it is to fix all the errors I continually get.

Comment: PHP's built in [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) may be a step in the right direction for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

PHP will only run on the server, not in the browser. Use javascript to do the client side validation. Keep your server side validation, and add SQL injection protection. If you don't know what that is, Google it and look at the `mysql_escape_string()` PHP function to start.

Answer (score 0):

YES! there are casses where you want to do server side as well as client side validation though in most cases you need only do client side BEFORE submitting then client side on submit. If you need to do both before and after submit a quick google search game me [this nice looking tutorial](http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-jquery-for-real-time-server-side-form-validation-1829.html)

and as always I recommend using [jQuery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) which has a function to compare two passwords

Comment: Client side validation can easily be circumvented by turning off javascript in the browser.

Comment: @ScottSaunders yes that is true an that's why validation is always required all the time ! I never said validation on server side shouldn't be done

Comment: You may want to rephrase this: "though in most cases you need only do client side "

Comment: I am building this project and told that I may use JavaScript, but I need to have a way of performing validation if the user has JavaScript turned off, that is why I was trying to figure this whole thing out.

Comment: unfortunately you can do client side validation without submitting to a page